# Guava EventBus in globally (singleton) and session based in Vaadin with Spring Boot

Tags: java, session, spring-boot, vaadin, guava

I'm trying to get the Guava `EventBus` as Singleton and session based in a `Vaadin` application with spring boot but i cannot get it working so far. The session based one works but not the singleton one.The idea is to implement a global notification service, so that specific users get informed in case of new events. I tried following:

```
public class Configuration{

    @Scope("singleton")
    @Bean
    public EventBus globalEventBus(){
       return new EventBus("globalEventBus");
    }

    @SessionScoped
    @Bean
    public EventBus eventBus(){
        return new EventBus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I solved it like this:

1. I wrapped the Eventbus in a custom class in my case "TimeSaverEventBus"
2. In TimeSaverUI I added a private instance of TimeSaverEventBus and added the public static method getEventBus():TimeSaverEventbus
3. I added static methods to TimeSaverEventbus calling timeSaverUI.getEventbus() and then accessing the private Eventbus instance.

The Code looks like this:

```
@SpringUI
public class TimeSaverUI extends UI {

private TimeSaverEventBus eventBus = new TimeSaverEventBus();

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    TimeSaverEventBus.register(this);
    updateContent();
}

private void updateContent() {
  ...
}

...

public static TimeSaverEventBus getTimeSaverEventbus() {
    return ((TimeSaverUI) getCurrent()).eventBus;
}
}
```

and the EvenBusWrapper:

```
public class TimeSaverEventBus implements SubscriberExceptionHandler {

private final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus(this);

public static void post(final Object event) {
    TimeSaverUI.getTimeSaverEventbus().eventBus.post(event);
}

public static void register(final Object object) {
    TimeSaverUI.getTimeSaverEventbus().eventBus.register(object);
}

public static void unregister(final Object object) {
    TimeSaverUI.getTimeSaverEventbus().eventBus.unregister(object);
}

@Override
public final void handleException(final Throwable exception,
                                  final SubscriberExceptionContext context) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

With implementing this in that way you are able to register and unregister event listeners or post events by calling the static methods of TimeSaverEventBus.

I really hope that is what you are looking for.

Cheers, 
Felix

Comment: Hi Felix, thx for your proposal, how it works when you want to inform all logged in users for example? Because I need two instances of the EventBus, one which should be session based and the other which should be global.

Comment: do you have to declare the scope for your singleton? I use it annotated with bean und the session eventbus is annotated with '@Bean' und '@UIScope' wich is a spring vaadin annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is use a name for your beans. So it would work something like this.

```
public class Configuration{

 @Scope("singleton")
 @Bean(name="globalEventBus")
 public EventBus globalEventBus(){
    return new EventBus("globalEventBus");
 }

 @SessionScoped
 @Bean(name="sessionEventBus")
 public EventBus eventBus(){
     return new EventBus();
 }
}
```

Then when you want to autowire use this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("globalEventBus")
private EventBus globalEventBus;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionEventBus")
private EventBus sessionEventBus;
```